# Chrome App fileSystem non-existent

Tags: javascript, file, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I'm writing a Chrome App.
I have in my manifest.json:

```
"permissions": [
    {"fileSystem": ["write", "retainEntries", "directory"]},
    "storage"
  ],
  "file_handlers": {
    "text": {
      "types": [
        "text/*"
      ]
    }
  }
```

In the console, if I eval:

```
chrome.fileSystem
```

I get:  `undefined`
It looks like either I don't have permissions right or I have to
do magic to "load" the fileSystem code.
Help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure the console is for your app?

Comment: When I have the Chrome App up, I click right and choose 
"Inspect" from the menu.  Functions that are custom to my app are defined when I enter them into the console, so looking pretty likely the console is for my app, but it was clever of you to think of this possible failure mode!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that when I rebooted chrome,
voila, chrome.fileSystem now works.
Even though I had closed and reopened the 
app many times with the bug persisting,
I needed to reboot Chrome. 
When al else fails, reboot!